# Is it possible to route all traffic from a set of kubernetes pods through another pod acting as a VPN client?

Tags: networking, vpn, kubernetes

I am a newbie in kubernetes, so I apologise if this turns out to be trivially documented elsewhere. It may be that I did not search the right terms.

Say I have three pods in my cluster for three services: `P1`, `P2` and `P3`.
I'd like to route all the traffic from and to pods `P1` and `P2` through a VPN, so that they can reach the services on an external network. At the same time, `P3` should  access the internet normally and not be able to use the VPN tunnel. I do not need `P3` to communicate with `P1` nor `P2`.

Is it possible to create another pod `P4` running an openVPN client so that `P1` and `P2` use `P4` as a gateway to the Internet while `P3` can access Internet normally?
If possible, I am looking to have a single gateway pod `P4`. `P4` will have health checks so that if it crashes, it gets recreated automatically. In the meantime that it crashed, `P1` and `P2` should not be able to access the Internet.

I saw that something like this may be possible by creating a new virtual network in which `P4` acts as a gateway and putting the pods for `P1` and `P2` in such network using an admission hook. Yet, I would not be sure on how to create this new virtual network and have the hunch that there may be more elegant ways to approach this.

I am aware that I will need to put a service in front of the `P4` pod to be able to get to it from the others.

Basically, I'd like all requests from `P1` to go to the service of `P4`, then to the pod `P4`, then through the VPN tunnel using the VPN client running on `P4`

Comment: Theoretically. But nobody does this in practice - these services are usually provided on the infrastructure level.

Comment: @drookie - can you elaborate on, or give some examples of, how to do so? Kubernetes _is_ infrastructure to some perspectives!

Comment: Then it would be just easy to solve this: the only thing to resolve would be a chicken/egg dilemma- "can a cluster router be inside this very same cluster", lol.